# Alert dialog is opening two times results crash of application

Tags: android

In my android app i am trying to click a button which does some calculation result a alert dialog. asking user yes or not.
Clicking yes perform the action and No dismiss the alert dialog.

Problem is when i am clicking the button very fast it opens two alert box some times , pressing yes in first alert dialog does its action but pressing yes on second result in crash.

What will be the best approach to solve this problem . Actually this is simple subjective logic that's  why i am not adding code here .

Answer (score 5):

Simply add:

```
if(dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
    dialog.show();
}
```

To your onClick() method. This checks to see if the dialog is showing or not, and only shows it if it isn't already visible.

You'll have to replace `dialog` with whatever your instance is called.

Comment: `if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) { ... }`

Comment: @SK9 Ah yes. A null check would be better here. Thank you.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder mEAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mHomeActivity,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);  i  creating my alert dialog like this.Now  how do i change the answer you provided ?